Issues sorting with Sequelize
I'm attempting to sort a code that has includes from multiple models, but it just won't work.
static async get(queryParams) {
        const {
            search,
            customer_id,
            graveyard_id,
            product,
            sort = "id",
            order = "ASC",
            page = 1,
            limit = 10,
            active = "all",
        } = queryParams;
        const offset = (page - 1) * limit;
    
        const where = {};
        const include = [
            {
                model: Graveperson,
                as: 'gravepersons',
                attributes: ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'description', 'birthdate', 'deathdate'],
                required: false,
            },
            {
                model: Graveyard,
                as: 'graveyard',
                attributes: ['id', 'name'],
                required: false,
            },
            {
                model: Customer,
                as: 'customer',
                attributes: ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'customer_number', 'email', 'phone_number'],
                required: false,
            },
            {
                model: Visit,
                as: 'visits',
                attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('MAX', Sequelize.col('visit_date')), 'latest_visit_date']],
                separate: true,
            },
            {
                model: VisitNew,
                as: 'visitsNew',
                attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('MAX', Sequelize.col('visit_date')), 'latest_visit_date_new']],
                separate: true,
            }
        ];
    
        if (customer_id) {
            where.customer_id = customer_id;
        }
        if (graveyard_id) {
            where.graveyard_id = graveyard_id;
        }
        if (search) {
            include.push({
                model: Graveperson,
                as: 'gravepersons',
                where: {
                    [Op.or]: [
                        Sequelize.where(
                            Sequelize.fn('concat', Sequelize.col('Graveperson.first_name'), ' ', Sequelize.col('Graveperson.last_name')),
                            { [Op.like]: `%${search}%` }
                        ),
                    ],
                },
                required: false,
            });
            include.push({
                model: Graveyard,
                as: 'graveyard',
                where: {
                    name: { [Op.like]: `%${search}%` }
                },
                required: false,
            });
            include.push({
                model: Customer,
                as: 'customer',
                where: {
                    [Op.or]: [
                        Sequelize.where(
                            Sequelize.fn('concat', Sequelize.col('Customer.first_name'), ' ', Sequelize.col('Customer.last_name')),
                            { [Op.like]: `%${search}%` }
                        ),
                    ],
                },
                required: false,
            });
        }
        if (active !== "all") {
            where.active = active;
        }
        if (product) {
            where.products = { [Op.like]: `%${product}%` };
        }
    
        try {
            const gravestones = await Gravestone.findAndCountAll({
                where,
                include,
                order: [[sort, order]],
                limit: parseInt(limit),
                offset: parseInt(offset),
            });
    
            const totalPages = Math.ceil(gravestones.count / limit);
    
            const products = await Product.findAll({
                attributes: ['id', 'name', 'color', 'period_start', 'period_end'],
                where: { active: 1 }
            });
            const productsMap = products.reduce((acc, product) => {
                acc[product.id] = product;
                return acc;
            }, {});
    
            const isInCurrentPeriod = (product) => {
                const currentDate = new Date();
                const currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
                const periodStartDate = new Date(`${currentYear}-${product.period_start}`);
                const periodEndDate = new Date(`${currentYear}-${product.period_end}`);
    
                if (periodEndDate < periodStartDate) {
                    if (currentDate < periodStartDate) {
                        periodStartDate.setFullYear(currentYear - 1);
                    } else {
                        periodEndDate.setFullYear(currentYear + 1);
                    }
                }
                return currentDate >= periodStartDate && currentDate <= periodEndDate;
            };
    
            const formattedGravestones = gravestones.rows.map(gs => {
                const productIds = JSON.parse(gs.products || '[]');
                let productColor = null;
                const productNames = productIds.map(id => productsMap[id] ? productsMap[id].name : "Unknown Product").join(", ");
                for (let id of productIds) {
                    const product = productsMap[id];
                    if (product && isInCurrentPeriod(product)) {
                        productColor = product.color;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                const gravepersonsNames = gs.gravepersons.map(gp => `${gp.first_name} ${gp.last_name}`).join(', ');
    
                return {
                    ...gs.toJSON(),
                    gravepersons_names: gravepersonsNames,
                    graveyard_name: gs.graveyard ? gs.graveyard.name : 'N/A',
                    customer_name: gs.customer ? `${gs.customer.first_name} ${gs.customer.last_name}` : 'N/A',
                    productNames,
                    productColor,
                };
            });
    
            return {
                gravestones: formattedGravestones,
                totalItems: gravestones.count,
                totalPages,
            };
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Failed to get gravestones:', error);
            throw error;
        }
    }

Attempting to sort results in this error:
Failed to get gravestones: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
I also tried this solution:
const order = [];
    if (sort && order) {
        const [alias, field] = sort.split('.');
        if (field && include.some(incl => incl.as === alias)) {
            order.push([{ model: include.find(incl => incl.as === alias).model, as: alias }, field, order]);
        } else {
            order.push([sort, order]);
        }
    }

Which did something, it did change the order of the results, but not correctly.
So, now I'm at a loss. ChatGPT is not being  too helpful, so now I turn to you smart people at Stack Overflow for help. Any clever ideas?
